# Angular controllers

Tags: angularjs, angular-controller

I have a Controller in which I have a variable `$scope.tasks`. In my nested controller I obtain some data from backend and want to assign that response which is say `$scope.editedTasks` to `$scope.tasks` in my parent controller. How can I achieve this?

Comment: some js could be useful

Comment: please show what you have tried?? a bit of you code help here to understand